# 2-opt to 3-opt for Travelling Salesman

Tags: java, graph, traveling-salesman

I am trying to convert my 2-opt implementation of the travelling salesman problem into a 3-opt. I understand that it is, in comparison to 2-opt, removing 3 edges and replacing them to hopefully get a better distance. I am having issue figuring out what to change/add to my 2-opt swap to make it three opt. The main problem I am having is how to make sure all 8 varieties of swaps are accounted for in a single swap function.
Thank you

2-opt code:

```
private static int[] TwoOpt(int[] TSP) {
        double best = totalDistance;
        int numCities = TSP.length;
        int visited = 0;
        int current = 0;
        int[] newTour = TSP;
        while (visited < numCities) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numCities - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < numCities; j++) {
                    int[] newerTour = Swap(i, j, newTour);
                    int newDistance = distance(newerTour);
                    if (newDistance < best) {
                        visited = 0;
                        best = newDistance;
                        newTour = newerTour;
                    }
                }
            }
            visited++;

        }
        return newTour;

    }

    private static int distance(int[] newTour) {
        int distance = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < newTour.length - 1; i++) {
            distance += mstList.get(i).get(i + 1).p;
        }
        distance += mstList.get(newTour.length).get(0).p;
        return distance;
    }

    private static int[] Swap(int i, int j, int[] tour) {
        int size = tour.length;
        int[] newerTour = new int[tour.length];
        for (int c = 0; c <= i - 1; c++) {
            newerTour[c] = tour[c];
        }
        int change = 0;
        for (int d = i; d <= j; d++) {
            newerTour[d] = tour[d - change];
            change++;
        }
        for (int e = j + 1; e < size; e++) {
            newerTour[e] = tour[e];
        }
        return newerTour;

    }
```

and this is what I have for the three-opt, no swap implemented yet.

```
private static int[] ThreeOpt(int[] TSP) {
        double best = totalDistance;
        int numCities = TSP.length;
        int visited = 0;
        int current = 0;
        int[] newTour = TSP;
        while (visited < numCities) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numCities - 2; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < numCities - 1; j++) {
                    for (int k = j + 1; k < numCities; k++) {
                        int[] newerTour = Swap(i, j, k, newTour);
                        int newDistance = distance(newTour);
                        if (newDistance < best) {
                            visited = 0;
                            best = newDistance;
                            newTour = newerTour;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            visited++;

        }
        return newTour;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actually only 4 forms of 3-opt.

break the tour into 3 parts A->,B->,C->

the 2-opt on the two edges connecting B to A and C are:

- A->,<-B,C->

i.e. just reverse the tour of B.

now for 3-opt

- A->,<-B,<-C
- A->,C->,B->
- A->,C->,<-B
- A->,<-C,B->

note that A->,<-B,C->, and A->,B->,<-C and A->,<-C,<-B are all 2-opt.

reversals are easy to implement and you only have to consider 4 variaties.